# How to allow an audio progress bar to be draggable on touch devices

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, mediaelement.js

I am serving audio files with mediaelement.js. In the browser I can click the progress bar of the song playing, and drag it with my mouse to different parts of the song, to play from that point.

On the ipad and iphone (and presumably other touchscreen devices), I cannot click and drag the bar; when I touch and hold down and drag, the entire browser moves. I can click on different parts of the progress part to change where the song is playing from, but I like the feel of dragging the progress bar around, and would like to reproduce this behavior for touch devices.

Is there a way to achieve this? Possibly modify the "focus" of the touch? Also, I am not attached to mediaelement.js, if there is a different library that can achieve this.

Comment: Just a guess as you didn't post the page -- try and make the handle element an <a href="javascript:void(0)" tag, not a div or the like.